# How to get the age from a birthdate using PDO & MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I don't know exactly how to put the code that is neccesary that show me the age with the birthdate that is in mysql ..always give me 1..can you please show me where is my error?

this is the code:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(f_nacimiento, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(f_nacimiento, '00-%m-%d')) AS age from PACIENTES where id_paciente = $_GET[id_paciente]";
echo print $age; ?>
```

in the db the row f_nacimiento is in date type (yyyy-mm-dd)

best regards!

Comment: Duplicate of manual entry http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-calculations.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is simply "1" because you are selecting a boolean expression.
That is, `X < Y` returns only 0 or 1.

There's a much easier way to do date arithmetic in MySQL.  The [DATEDIFF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function returns the number of days between two dates.

```
$query = "SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), f_nacimiento) / 365.25) AS age
    FROM PACIENTES
    WHERE id_paciente = ?";

if (($stmt = $pdo->prepare($query)) === false ) {
  die(print_r($pdo->errorInfo(), true));
}

$id_paciente = $_GET["id_paciente"];
if ($stmt->execute(array($id_paciente)) === false) {
  die(print_r($stmt->errorInfo(), true));
}

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  echo $row["age"] . "\n";
}
```

The table I tested this with is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `PACIENTES` (
  `id_paciente` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `f_nacimiento` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_paciente`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

PS: The example code above shows two other important habits of PDO programming:

- Use query parameters, do not interpolate strings directly into SQL.
- Check for error status returned from prepare() and execute().

---

Re your comment, needing to display the age in years, months.  Here's my second try (with days thrown in for fun):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR
   , f_nacimiento
   , NOW()
   ) AS Years,
   TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH
   , f_nacimiento
       + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, f_nacimiento, NOW()) YEAR
   , NOW()
   ) AS Months,
   TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY
   , f_nacimiento
       + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, f_nacimiento, NOW()) MONTH
   , NOW()
   ) AS Days
FROM PACIENTES
WHERE id_paciente = 1;
```

Comment: same result... and I change ? to ` $_GET[id_paciente]` and this too above of "select" `$id_paciente = (int)` but the same result...always 1

Comment: I have edited the above code after testing it with PHP 5.3.15 and MySQL 5.5.31.  It does work.

Comment: I already change DATE to date in the db and works but I don't know why show me the number 1 too?? my engine is MYSAM

Comment: never mind I put your code with `echo print $age;`, so when I delete it just show me the right age..thank you for your support!  best regards!

Comment: I edited the above code example once more.  I had left `$id_paciente = 1;` as a dummy value, so I changed it to use `$id_paciente = $_GET["id_paciente"];`

Comment: yes, I already change that. Thank you for your support!  Best Regards

Comment: ...it show me the month of birhtday but I need to show the date like this:  Age: 34 years, 11 month...the month to the next birhtday not the month of his/her birhtday... best regards!

Comment: Ah, now I understand better what you mean.  See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

use this query instead, and since you're using pdo use the prepared statements

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW()) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM f_nacimiento) age FROM pacientes WHERE id_paciente = ?
```

and for the php

```
$dbh = new PDO(.....
$st = $dbh->prepare($query);
$st->execute([(string)$_GET['id_paciente']]);
var_dump($st->fetchAll());
```

Comment: give me this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' `

Comment: Using "short array syntax" (square brackets instead of `array()`) only works in PHP 5.4 and later.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the $_GET variable correctly in a string.

```
$query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(f_nacimiento, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(f_nacimiento, '00-%m-%d')) AS age from PACIENTES where id_paciente = $_GET[id_paciente]";
```

to:

```
$query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(f_nacimiento, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(f_nacimiento, '00-%m-%d')) AS age from PACIENTES where id_paciente = \"" . $_GET['id_paciente'] . "\"";
// Do the query....
```

Comment: -1 for several reasons:  Most importantly, this answer does not address the query problem at all.  Fails to advise using query parameters.  Uses quotes needlessly for a value that is presumably an integer.  Uses double-quotes instead of single-quotes to delimit a string literal in SQL.